# Error occurs while saving the package : The part /xl/sharedStrings.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller

Tags: java, apache-poi

While streaming a large `.xlsx` file to the browser from java code I am getting an exception.

```
Exception: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package:

The part /xl/sharedStrings.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@32c7a1ed.
```

This issue is occurring for the files which are taking long time to download, for other files which are taking short time to download are working fine.

Comment: Set `org.apache.poi` log4j logger to level `DEBUG` or `ALL`, it should spit out the inner reason. E.g. for me it was `Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream`.

Comment: In my case it was due to an HTTP timeout of my request, which closes the output stream. It took me a little to find out because my HTTP request went through a **proxy,** which was the one that timed out.

A possible solution is to avoid sending synchronous requests for big file exports, but instead use a websocket which tells the frontend when the export is done and ready to be requested for download.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Here is how I solved:

Change the Workbook class to SXSSFWorkbook:

```
Workbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
```

If you have autosize (like I did), add the following call to the Sheet object:

```
sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();
```

Very important! Don't forget to dispose the Workbook, otherwise temp files will NOT be deleted:

```
wb.write(response.outputStream);
response.outputStream.close();
wb.dispose();
```

More info [here](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/index.html#SXSSF+(Since+POI+3.8+beta3))